# Converting current HTML page to PDF

Tags: html, node.js, angular

I am using html-pdf library to convert html to PDF. I am having my html as

```
<div id="newDiv" style="text-align: center;color:royalblue;">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn" (click)="showData()">Basic</button>
```

at node side when i am trying to convert it into PDF at the location. It is giving me the PDF but style is missing. Can anyone tell me any good solution. Stucked from yesterday on this

Comment: is the button is showing in the pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Since one of the tags is Angular, I would suggest using windows.print(). It works in Angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pdfmake` library to make easy and fastest way to generate the PDF from Html

```js
 var app = angular.module("app", []);

 app.controller("listController", ["$scope",
   function($scope) {
     $scope.employees = [{
       firstName: "rajeh",
       lastName: "gatla",
       gender: "mgale",
       mobile: "8143445171"
     }, {
       firstName: "sathi",
       lastName: "wesd",
       gender: "madfgle",
       mobile: "8143445171"
     }, {
       firstName: "gjds",
       lastName: "hs",
       gender: "madfhsdfle",
       mobile:"8143445171"
     }];

     $scope.export = function() {
       html2canvas(document.getElementById('exportthis'), {
         onrendered: function(canvas) {
           var data = canvas.toDataURL();
           var docDefinition = {
             content: [{
               image: data,
               width: 500,
             }]
           };
           pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).download("test.pdf");
         }
       });
     }
   }
 ]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.22/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="listController">
    <div id="exportthis">
      <table border='1'>
      <tbody> <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees"> <td>{{emp.firstName}}</td> <td>{{emp.lastName}}</td> <td>{{emp.gender}}</td> <td>{{emp.mobile}}</td> </tr> </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="export()">export</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```